# Databricks SQL restful API to query delta table

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

As of today, can we use any Databricks SQL Restful API to query Delta Tables stored in ADLS from any external UI?There is some information mentioned over this link https://docs.databricks.com/sql/api/index.html? but not sure how to use them!!

Checked in Databricks documentation about how this can be implemented but dint find any proper way out.
Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: 12.04.2023rd: [SQL Statement Execution API](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/api/statements.html) is in the public preview since March.

The API documentation that you linked is primarily for maintaining SQL warehouses, queries, dashboards & alerts.

API for executing SQL queries is currently is in the private preview and should be available in the near future (but no ETA yet). You can watch recent [quarterly product roadmap webinar](https://www.databricks.com/p/webinar/productroadmapwebinar) to find more details about upcoming API.

P.S. You can easily implement your own API by wrapping one of the SQL connectors - for [Python](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-python), [Node.js](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-nodejs), or [Go](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-go).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply and suggestion.